# Shell script to check if the process is already running and exit if yes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jmeter, scripting-language

I have a shell script with methods `status()` and `start()`. The code is below:

```
#function to check the jmeter processes running
status(){
     PID=$(ps -ef | grep jmeter|grep -v grep)
     echo "The jmeter processes running are: \n$PID"
}

#function to run the .jmx file given by the user at run time
start(){
     echo "Please enter the file name .jmx extension"
     read file
     echo "Please enter the log file name .jtl extension"
     read log_file
     sh /home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t $file -l $log_file &
}
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
case "$1" in
        start)
            jmeter_start
            ;;
         status)
            jmeter_status
            ;;
          *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {start|status}"
            exit 1
        esac
   shift
done
```

now when I run this script, I have to check if it is already running and if it is running I have to exit. Let me know how to do this.

Comment: Where is this check taking place? In the `start` function?

Comment: `start` does not run in the background; it starts a different process in the background then immediately exists.

Comment: @RowlandB That is what I was trying to implement but couldn't do it

Comment: @chepner yes. I am running the jmeter command to execute the .jmx file in background.

Answer (score 4):

Add a flag at the beginning of the function and set it to 1, before the end of the function set it to 0, query it however you like.

```
#function to check the jmeter processes running
status(){
     PID=$(ps -ef | grep jmeter|grep -v grep)
     echo "The jmeter processes running are: \n$PID"
}

#function to run the .jmx file given by the user at run time
start(){
     export start_flag=1
     echo "Please enter the file name .jmx extension"
     read file
     echo "Please enter the log file name .jtl extension"
     read log_file
     sh /home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t $file -l $log_file &
     export start_flag=0
}
```

Another option would be writing to an external file and query it.

Comment: I didn't understand this. Can you explain what you meant by query it

Comment: Either use `$start_flag` or read from the file you wrote to using `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have most of it already. You should be able to use the code from `status` that gets the PID and just check if it exists. If it does, output some error and exit. Otherwise, do what you already have.

```
start(){
   PID=$(ps -ef | grep jmeter|grep -v grep)

   if [ -z $PID ]; then
       echo "Error: JMeter already running"
       exit
   fi

   echo "Please enter the file name .jmx extension"
   read file
   echo "Please enter the log file name .jtl extension"
   read log_file
   sh /home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t $file -l $log_file &
```

}

Comment: but I want to check it for that particular `start()` method. I have updated the question. Please check

Comment: What differentiates two `start` functions? It doesn't really matter if two invocations of `start` run at the same time, as long as you don't wind up with two instances of `jmeter` running in the background.

Comment: @chepner yeah. but i don't want to run 2 `start()` at the same time

Comment: @chepner I have edited the question please check and help